# Split array into chunks of a total value

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of values that I need to split in chunks of a total value. Each chunks total value should not be higher than 4.

```
var arr = [1, 2, 4, 1, 1, 4, 2, 2, 1, 4];
```

This should become something like:

```
var chunks = [[1, 2, 1], [4], [1, 2, 1], [4], [2], [4];
```

So I need all values of the original array split up into chunks of variable size, but its total value should never be higher than 4 in this case.

Comment: nice idea, what have you tried?

Comment: are all values between 1 and 4? do you need to minimise number of chunks?

Comment: this is more of an algorithmic question

Comment: @Kepotx All values are between 1 and 4, and I do need to minimise the number of chunks, each chunk should be 4, except the last one, that will be the rest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```js
var arr = [1, 2, 4, 1, 1, 4, 2, 2, 1, 4];
var max = 4;
var chunks = [];

arr.forEach(x => {
  // get the first chunk that the value can be added to
  var chunk = chunks.find(c => {

    // calculate sum of chunk
    var sum = c.reduce((a, b) => a + b);

    // return true if the sum of the chunk + current value in array iteration is less than max
    return sum + x <= max;
  });
  
  if (chunk)
    chunk.push(x); // found a chunk. Add value to that.
  else
    chunks.push([x]); // Can't be added to existing chunks. Create new one.
});

console.log(chunks);
```

Comment: This seems to do the trick :) Would you mind explaining the code a bit more? Thanks!

Comment: I've added more comments. If it's not enough let me know which part you need explained.

Comment: Thanks, I tried recreating it myself according to your example and I get it now :)