# How to create array chunk based on property value

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

I have an array like this:

```
const arr = [{flagCount: 3, rank:1}, {flagCount: 3, rank:2}, {flagCount: 1, rank:3}, {flagCount: 1,rank:4}, {flagCount: 1, rank:5}, {flagCount: 2, rank:6},{flagCount: 2, rank:7},{flagCount: 2,rank:8},{flagCount: 1,rank:9}]
```

now, I want to group the objects in chunks, where a single chunk will contain objects whose total flag count will be 3 or less (*should not be more than* 3) -

for example, the resultant array should look like:

```
const resultArr = [[{flagCount: 3,rank:1}], [{flagCount: 3,rank:2}], [{flagCount: 1,rank:3}, {flagCount: 1,rank:4}, {flagCount: 1,rank:5}], [{flagCount: 2,rank:6}], [{flagCount: 2,rank:7}], [{flagCount: 2,rank:8}, {flagCount: 1,rank:9}]]
```

i.e, in any given chunk, the flagCount value does not exceed 3.

Also, the order of rank must be maintained in the chunk array as well!

how do I achieve this?

Comment: Seems like a simple `for` loop would be able to achieve this. Have you tried anything? Done any research into solving this yourself?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Split array into chunks of a total value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49402982/split-array-into-chunks-of-a-total-value)

Comment: @HereticMonkey Unfortunately not! Imagine each object in the given array comes with a rank - for example 1st object has rank 1.. 2nd object has rank 2..  and so on. The chunked array must maintain the ranks in the same order.. The chunked array should not randomly pick objects and put in the nested array.

Comment: Something like [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/NrX40W)?  If that meets your needs I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?  (Please mention @jcalz to notify me if you reply)

Comment: @jcalz I just checked the link and ran the code. The log seems like what I am looking for. I will really appreciate if you could explain in detail. I am using Typescript and the Object in the array contains lot more data than I have shown

Comment: @ArupBhattacharya I did downvote. You should never post a question without showing an attempt. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Well, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74058336/2887218) is almost identical to my approach; I would explain but probably the other answer should just be edited to include more information if it's necessary

Comment: @RuanMendes I know I should not post! Unfortunately I am running out of time and I can not just post my attempt from my Project code as I have signed a strict NDA and any compromise on that would simply risk my job. So I decided to create a simpler version and post for help from the community. Hope you understand.

Comment: I didn't downvote but the comment about being too rushed to conform to community guidelines is concerning to me.  It indicates that you do not have the time to engage appropriately and that it's probably not worth others' time to compensate for that.  Again, not going to downvote, but I think I'll stop watching this question now and go elsewhere.

Comment: @jcalz I beg to be pardoned - and I really mean it. I never had any intention to value the community. I have been getting help since I started to code from the very beginning of my carrier.

Comment: What if an object has a flagCount that is greater than 3?

Comment: @trincot Good question! I have talked to the data science team and they confirmed that the it should either be 1 or 2 or 3.

Answer (score 1):

It can be solved using a temporal array to store each chunk while iterating through items of your initial array.

```
const arr = [{flagCount: 3}, {flagCount: 3}, {flagCount: 1}, {flagCount: 1}, {flagCount: 1}, {flagCount: 2},{flagCount: 2},{flagCount: 2},{flagCount: 1}];

// your final array
const chunkedArr = [];
// a temp array to store each chunk
let currentChunk = [];

arr.forEach(x => {
  // check if sum of chunk's total count plus current item's count is > 3
  const currentChunkTotalCount = currentChunk.reduce((p, c) => p + c.flagCount, 0);

  if (currentChunkTotalCount + x.flagCount > 3) {
    chunkedArr.push(currentChunk);
    currentChunk = [x];
  } else {
    currentChunk.push(x);
  }
});

if (currentChunk.length) chunkedArr.push(currentChunk);

console.log(chunkedArr);
```

check fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rzxqky06/1/

Comment: Thank you so much. Since you are iterating on each object in a linear way - you do not need to consider the rank associated with each object .. am I right ?

Comment: By rank, you mean index? There is no need to consider it, if I correctly understand your question. 

Just a note, you could optimize your code if you need the minimum amount of chunks. If you don't care about the minimum amount of chunks, the above works as expected.

Finally, consider upvoting & marking as accepted the answers that helped you.